# Magento - Difference Between Import All Products/import Product Stock?

Tags: magento

What is difference Difference Between Import All Products/import Product Stock when your importing a profile in Magento? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import All Products is for all product data. Import Product Stock is just the inventory quantities.